# Is there a way to replace brackets in a string inside a .json file?

Tags: java, android, json

I am working on an app that has a huge .json database, a lot of the strings I need in the .json file have curly brackets ("{", "}") inside them, which I do not want, like this:

```
[
      {
        "name": "Whatever",
        "entries": [
          "If something something {28} + {41.6} something"
        ]
      }
]
```

And I need to get the string as "If something something 28 + 41.6 something".

I remove them by fetching the string I need and using this method:

```
public String formatText(String text) {

    String newtext = text.replaceAll("\\{", "").replaceAll("\\}", "");

   return newtext;
}
```

That works but makes everything really slow.
I had other characters in the file, like "@", that I had no problem removing in a text editor by selecting all of them and replacing by the empty string. But if I use the same logic with the curly brackets it will also remove the json object brackets.

Anyone can think of a way to edit this file and remove only the brackets inside the strings?

(I've thought of making a method that copies the strings, formats them and send them to a new .json, but that would be really innefective timewise, because there is a lot of different values inside every object.)

Comment: You should use a JSON parser.

Comment: you may use regex if the escaped string follows some pattern

Comment: what json database is it a .json file or database with .db extension .?

Comment: is the json coming from an array or just a string of json?

Comment: @SLaks I've tried some online JSON parsers and editors, but none had the functionality to select every of a character in the formatted JSON.

Comment: @Beloo there is some patterns that could get about 70% of the brackets out, but that would leave me with the exceptions.

Comment: @Sush it is a .json file.

Comment: @al_khalid an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna use the find/replace functionality of text editors - using IDE like intelij - there is an option to replace stuff by regex. 
E.g. this `(?=\S.)({|})` should cover your case with braces in string only, while not touching json syntax braces. If you have other unique cases - they should be included in regex. Example - https://regex101.com/r/wbIgKX/1

Though, I would propose to create a proper json parser class specifically to deal with your stuff.

Comment: I guess I need to learn regex. But I made a few changes to fit the problem and got (?=...)(\{|\}). Which solved it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the JSON file is formatted like your example, you can check whether the line contains anything else then whitespaces and { or }

If the line contains anything else, then replace the brackets

If not, then don't replace

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

convert the json array into JObject and then  you can grab each individual element. then parse through that and replace the curly brackets.

```
String example =  jObject.SelectToken("entries");
"entries": [
          "If something something {28} + {41.6} something"
        ]
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried multiple way to resolve this issue but directly you cannot replace it. There is way to do it , First iterate the json and check whether the line contains curly brace or not. If contains then you can use str.replaceAll("[{}]", " ");. This will remove the all the curly braces and gives you the string without braces.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve is:

```
final String finalString = listId.getList().stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(",")).toString();
```

listId is a JsonArray.